# If $\ell_1$ is a hyperbolic line, show there exists a perpendicular line $\ell_2$ such that $p\in \ell_2$ where $p \in \mathbb{H}\setminus\ell_1$

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I am working within the upper half plane.

I broke this question into three categories:

1. $\ell_1$ is a vertical line.
2. $\ell_1$ is a semi-circle and $p$ is directly above the center of $\ell_1$.
3. $\ell_1$ is a semi-circle and $p$ is not directly above the center of $\ell_1$.

I have proved the first two cases, but I am now stuck on the last case.

For case three it is clear that $\ell_2$ must be a also be a semi-circle. Since both lines are centered on $\mathbb{R}$, we can tell that they intersect at $\pi/2$ rad if and only if $|c_1-c_2|^2+r_2^2=r_1^2$. Where $|c_1-c_2|$ is the distance between both lines centers and $r_i$ corresponds to the radius of the respective line.

We also know that $p\in\ell_2 \implies r_2 = \sqrt{(Re(p)-c_2)^2+Im(p)^2}$. Now substituting the second equation into the first gives us the following:
$$2c_2^2-2c_1c_2+c_2^2+Re(p)^2-2c_2Re(p)+c^2+Im(p)^2=r_1^2$$
Isolating for $c_2$ using the quadratic equation gives us the following:
$$c_2 = \frac{2(c_1+Re(p)) \pm \sqrt{8r_1^2-4c_1^2+8c_1Re(p)-8Im(p)^2-4Re(p)^2}}{4}$$
If the statment that im trying to prove is always true, we should see that $8r_1^2-4c_1^2+8c_1Re(p)-8Im(p)^2-4Re(p)^2 = 0$ for all cases. However considering $c_1=r_1=1, Re(p) = 2, \Im(10)$ we see that $8r_1^2-4c_1^2+8c_1Re(p)-8Im(p)^2-4Re(p)^2<0$.

This leads me to believe that the question is flawed as I have just demonstrated that when $\ell_1$ is a semi-circle with center at 1 and radius 1, there does not not exist a another semi-circle such that it can intersect $\ell_2$ and hit the point $p=2 + 10i$.

I would appreciate if someone could verify my proof and/or point out any flaws in it.

Comment: If you can do it for a vertical line, apply an isometry that takes this line to your given line.

Comment: @markvs I am not quite sure what you mean. If $\ell_1$ is a vertical line they $\ell_2$ is just a semi-circle with the same center and the radius is just the distance from the center to the point $p$. For simplicity, let me refer to the semi-circle that would have been $\ell_1$ in part 3 as $\ell_3$. If I apply a mobius transformation from $\ell_1$ (the vertical) to $\ell_3$, I can confirm that there exists a point where $\ell_2$ and $\ell_3$ intersect because mobius transformation preserve angles?

Comment: For every two bi-infinite geodesics on the hyperbolic plane there is an isometry that takes one to another. And yes, the isometries are conformal, preserve angles.